# unique_ptr can't instantiate class because it's abstract

Tags: c++, abstract-class, smart-pointers

I have an abstract class(Component)
and this class should be owned by another class(GameObject).
Every `GameObject` has a vector of components.

Header:

```
 class Component;
        class GameObject{
        public:
            GameObject();
            virtual ~GameObject();
            void addComponent(std::unique_ptr<Component> component);
            void addComponent(Component* component);
        void removeComponent(std::unique_ptr<Component> component);

        virtual void update();
        std::string getInfo();
        
        //return the first component of type T
        template<typename T>
        T* getComponent(){
            for(auto& component : components){
                if(dynamic_cast<T*>(component.get())){
                    return dynamic_cast<T*>(component.get());
                }
            }
            return nullptr;
        }

        // return the component with the type T
        template<typename T>
        std::vector<T*> getComponents(){
            std::vector<T*> components;
            for(auto component : this->components){
                if(dynamic_cast<T*>(component)){
                    components.push_back(dynamic_cast<T*>(component));
                }
            }
            return components;
        }

        
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;

    };
class Component
    {
    private:
    public:
        Component() = delete;
        virtual ~Component() = 0;
        virtual std::string getInfo();
        
        
        //the game object this component is attached to
        GameObject* gameObject;
        
    };
```

source:

```
std::string GameObject::getInfo() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << typeid(*this).name();
    for (Uint32 i = 0; i < this->components.size(); i++) {
        ss << typeid(components[i]).name() << " " << this->components[i]->getInfo();
    }
}


void GameObject::addComponent(std::unique_ptr<Component> component) {
    components.push_back(std::move(component));
}
void GameObject::addComponent(Component* component) {
    components.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<Component>(*component)));
}
void GameObject::removeComponent(std::unique_ptr<Component> component) {
    for (auto it = components.begin(); it != components.end(); it++) {
        if (it->get() == component.get()) {
            components.erase(it);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR: cannot instantiate abstract class. file: memory line 3416

Comment: Well, you didn't provide 3416 lines of code so clearly the problem is not what you pasted. Provide a [mre]

Comment: If I should guess, the issue is probably with ```std::make_unique<Component>```. That's the same as ```std::unique_ptr<Component>(new Component(...))``` which clearly cannot work with an abstract base class.

Comment: Please read carefully when to use `std::move` you are using it in wrong way.

Comment: Looks like your GameObject isn't intended to be instantiated, it still has pure virtual functions. and what you need to do is instantiate derived classes that have that pure virtual function implemented and then add them to the components list.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That looks to be line 3416 in `<memory>`, which I can well believe is at least that long.

Comment: The compiler should give a backtrace of where the problem was caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
void GameObject::addComponent(Component* component) {
    components.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<Component>(*component)));
}
```

When you dereference `component`, as far as the compiler knows you still just have a `Component`, not the actual instantiation--it can't call the proper copy constructor.

The solution is to just deleted this member function entirely.  You already have a version that takes a `std::unique_ptr<Component>`, so require the user of `GameObject` to provide the `unique_ptr` in all cases.

Comment: Dont use this overload only use the `addComponent(std::unique_ptr<Component> component)` version. The code you show cannot guarantee ownership will be correct and seems more like a hack to get things to compile.

Comment: @PepijnKramer - `std::unique_ptr` already assumes ownership.  If a `unique_ptr` has two owners, then its constraint has already been violated.

Comment: std::unique_ptr doesn't assume, it models ownership.  With the "naked" Component* it is possible to pass in a non-owning pointer or a pointer that has been 'newed' outside this block and still has a matching 'delete' somewhere. So that's why you need to explicitly pass in a std::unique_ptr<Component> to remove that confusion and explicitly model that GameObject will take ownership.

Comment: I think we're arguing semantics at this point, since your last comment is suggesting exactly what my answer says.  I copied the non-working code from the question, explained why it's not working, and my last paragraph says to just delete that code.

Comment: Fair points. I see now what you mean :)